# How can I create a message on check in response in Foursquare?

Tags: asp.net, httprequest, asihttprequest, foursquare

I am developing one Dot Net application with Foursquare API.

I need to post Welcome message to each Check of the user in of the selected Venue.

Can anyone explain the endpoint or link of the request ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your the part in your code with the problem. Please be more specific.

Comment: Dim parameters As New NameValueCollection

         
         parameters.Add("oauth_token", "Token")
        'parameters.Add("text", "welcome")
 
        Dim url As String = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/CheckIn Id/addcomment"
        Dim wc = New WebClient()
        wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        '   wc.UseDefaultCredentials.ToString()
        Dim result = wc.UploadValues(url, "POST", parameters)

But Getting 405 Fobidden Error

Comment: please edit your question and paste the code over there so we can easily read it